# Get the max value for a specific column

Tags: r

I have a file like :

```
"run","tick"
"1","0"
"1","1"
  ...
"1","289"       <-------------
"2","0"
  ...
"2","337"       <-------------
  ...
```

I would like to get the maximum "tick" for a certain "run", like below :

```
for(run==1) 
   max = max(tick)
```

How can I do this in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
aggregate(tick~run, df, max)
#   run tick
#1   1  289
#2   2  337
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Max=max(tick)), by=run]
#   run Max
#1:   1 289
#2:   2 337
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    group_by(run)
    summarise(Max=max(tick))
```

Or as commented by @Joshua Ulrich

```
 with(df, ave(tick, run, FUN=max))
 #[1] 289 289 289 337 337
```

Or from @David Arenburg's comments

```
 with(df, tapply(tick, run, max))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(run = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), tick = c(0, 1, 289, 
 0, 337)), .Names = c("run", "tick"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: or `with(df, ave(tick, run, FUN=max))`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks, Not sure he wants to mutate or summarise

Comment: Or `with(df, tapply(tick, run, max))` (my personal favorite)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  That is good one.  I guess, it might be faster than `aggregate`

Comment: It's for sure faster than `aggregate`. It could give a good fight to the rest of the solutions too (for not so big data sets)